# Why does "applying" a probability to a set give the exact answer (axiomatically)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Please link to any duplicates (I'm sure there is one I just cannot phrase this in a single search query)

Consider the set of integers $S=\{1,2,\ldots,100\}$. Choose $x$ in this set randomly (every element has an equal probability of being chosen), the probability that $5$ divides $x$ is $\frac{1}{5}$ (assume we happen to know this for sure, without proof). It turns out then that there must be $100\cdot\frac{1}{5}=20$ multiples of $5$ in $S$. Why, axiomatically, is it the case that gives the exact answer? Is it true generally that $P(A)|X|=|\{x\in X \text{ where } P(A) \text{ “true” for } x\}|$?

"Axiomatically" here is meant loosely (but not too loosely), obviously this result is intuitive and the way we found the probability 5 divides $x$ was presumably by doing $\frac{20}{100}$, but I'm hoping for a more convincing explanation.

Comment: Recall that probability of an event $|A|$ in an equiprobable sample space $|X|$ is given by $\dfrac{|A|}{|X|}$.  It follows then that $\dfrac{|A|}{|X|}\cdot |X| = |A|$

Comment: If all outcomes have an *equal* probability of occurring (not always true!) then it is the axiom of additivity of probabilities for *disjoint* outcomes that leads to the result you ask about: $P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$ and likewise for more than two outcomes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choosing $x$ randomly with equal probability means assigning probability $1/100$ to each element of $S$. The general situation is as follows: If $K$ is a subset of $S$, the probability that $x$ lies in $K$ is given by $\sum_{x\in K}p(x) = \sum_{x\in K}1/100 = |K|/100$. In the case that $K$ consists of the multiples of $5$, $|K| = 20$, and $P[x\in K] = 20/100 = 1/5$.

Answer (score 1):

To answer a question with a question: Why shouldn't it give a precise answer?  I think the reason to even feel like it wouldn't be precise in the first place, is that perhaps you feel "It's probability, so it shouldn't be totally precise." But the thing is, the answer isn't saying "For any random selection of a number from $S$, it will be precisely 1/5 divisible by 5" or something like that.  The 1/5 itself quantifies a probability, where that probability is observable only in an imprecise way: By repeating experiments any arbitrary number of times and observing outcomes which converge on average to 1/5.  So that's where the fuzziness is, not in the probability itself, but in the way that this probability manifests in empirical events.

And the probability itself should not be imprecise, because we stipulated something precise about it: That any number from $S$ is drawn with probability precisely 1/100.  Since that precision was baked into the question from the beginning, it should not be surprising that the answer is correspondingly precise.

Of course, to a degree I'm guessing at why you would be in any doubt about getting a precise answer.  I may simply not understand what it is that you're trying to ask.